# SQL Database Not Updating | JavaScript | Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, discord, discord.js

UPDATE: I believe the problem was that items in my database were originally set to NULL, and therefore couldn't change to an int. If anyone is stumbling upon this thread because they have the same question, try changing NULL to 0.

I'm making a Discord bot using JavaScript, node.js, and discord.js, and I'm using SQL to implement an economy system and a store system. The economy system is working great, but I'm having some troubles with the early stages off the store system. There aren't any actual errors popping up, but when I use the `buy` command, it sends a message that I bought one of whatever I said after the buy command. However, it doesn't actually update the database, and when I check with another command what is in my inventory, it says that there's no value in the spot where it should say the new item. I've checked capitalization and such. If anyone knows why this is happening, I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks! (Also, I'm using sqlite.)

The code for my `buy` command:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    const buy = (item) => {
        if (message.content.length > 5) {
            if (sql.get(`SELECT "${item}" FROM "${message.guild.id}" WHERE userId = "${message.member.id}" AND "${item}" IS NOT NULL`)) {
                sql.run(`UPDATE "${message.guild.id}" SET "${item}" = "${item}" WHERE userId = "${message.member.id}"`);
                message.channel.send(`${message.author}, one ${item} was added to your inventory.`);
            }
        }
    }
    const cart = (shopper) => {
        if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "buy " + shopper)) buy(shopper);
    }
    cart("Sullustan steak");
    cart("cape");
    cart("Roddy-Mobile");
    cart("fried Rodian");
    cart("pulse cannon");
});
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read into MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.com) and Mongoose (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/). MongoDB is a database software wich fully integrates with NodeJS, and Mongoose is a library to access that database in an easy and concise way.

Comment: I already have database software, and I'm using sqlite to insert sql into my program. I'll look into Mongoose, but I don't think that's it.

Comment: Valid point, didn't think that far. No, Mongoose is only an interface to MongoDB, you can't use it to interact with SQL.

Comment: From a security standpoint this is bad practice, I'm almost certain this would be vulnerable to sql injection, I'd suggest sanitising your inputs, namely "shopper" and potentially looking at a way of access the DB without a direct string, using stored procedures is one potential option, I know this does not directly address your issue but I feel it's worth noting.

Comment: Thank you @Madison Courto. I'll look into doing that once I get the basics of this working.

Comment: Never used his library- does sql.tun return an int indicating how many rows were updated? Was 1 row updated? If not, is there actually a row where that userid exists? Is the update even run? The update only fires if the user is already holding an item? What if item is null initially?

Comment: @CaiusJard The item is null initially, there is a row where the user exists because a new row is made when someone joins the server and their userId is added to the table and is what the bot is looking for when it says ```message.member.id```. As for the sql.run/int question, I think I've found a better way, using the .then() method. I'll work on if the user is already holding an item once I get this part done.
This is just the basics of the command right now.

Comment: If the item is null initially, and you ahve a select that says "select item.." but the item is null, and it's translated by whatever db access library this is, to a javascript null, then I'm not sure the update will run? (`if(null)` in js is like `if(false)`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that items in my database were originally set to NULL, and therefore couldn't change to an int. If anyone is stumbling upon this thread because they have the same question, try changing NULL to 0.